# Сортировка одномерного массива

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

Задача заключается в том, что дан массив действительных чисел a1, a2, ..., a2n. Необходимо получить a1, a2n, a2, a2n -1, ..., an, an + 1.

Говоря простым языком, если дан массив из пяти чисел, например: `1 2 3 4 5`,
то в результате необходимо получить: `1 5 2 4 3`.

Пытался отсортировать массив следующим образом, но что-то пошло не так:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= arr_size / 2.0; i++) {
    double temp = arr[i + 1];
    arr[i + 1] = arr[arr_size - i];
    arr[arr_size - i] = temp;
}
```

Comment: В первую очередь следует определить, что означает  " таким образом". Потом сделать. И уж если чего-то не получается, показать свои попытки.

Comment: Если функция должна преобразить массив из 5 конкретных цифр, то тут сортировка не нужна - просто пишите результат и все. Ну а если вам нужна действительно сортировка, то хотя бы потрудитесь написать: какое условие у этой сортировки. Ведб сдесь оно может быть какое угодно.

Comment: Что-то легче не стало. Это вообще что означает: a1, a2, ..., a2n. Ладно это, но вот это: a1, a2n, a2, a2n -1, ..., an, an + 1 - вы серьезно? Прям так и в условии задачи, которую вы пытаетесь решить?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, серьезно, четко переписал условие из задания лабараторной работы в колледже, сам в шоке))

Comment: жестко у вас там...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я верно понял ваш алгоритм, то ваш алгоритм заключается в следующем:
У вас есть исходный массив. Далее вам нужно его преобразовать следующим образом: **читать числа из исходного массива поочередно то с начала массива, то с конца**.

[Вот код](http://cpp.sh/3vkw6), который будет делать то, что вам нужно(**без создания нового массива, путем модификации существующего**).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    const int arrsize = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrsize/2; ++i)
    {
       int temp = a[arrsize - 1];
       for (int j = arrsize - 1; j > (i * 2 + 1); --j)
       {
           a[j] = a[j - 1];
       }
       a[i * 2 + 1] = temp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arrsize; ++i)
        std::cout << a[i];

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод будет: `1,5,2,4,3`.

Для массива большей длины также будет работать.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вместо `arr[arr_size-i]` поставить `arr[arr_size-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Предложу и свою версию:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Input number of members\n";
    int nMembers;
    std::cin >> nMembers;
    std::vector<int> arr(nMembers, 0);
    std::cout << "Input array\n";
    for (auto &i : arr) {
        std::cin >> i;
    }
    std::vector<int> nov(arr.size(), 0);

    bool val = false;
    for (auto i = arr.begin(), j = --arr.end(), l = nov.begin(); l != nov.end(); ++l) {
        if (!val) {
            *l = *i;
            i++;
            val = true;
        }
        else {
            *l = *j;
            j--;
            val = false;
        }
    }

    for (const auto &i : nov) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```